How to include multiple docker compose files that share a service declaratively
Let's say we have four services: A, B, C, and D.
Service A requires services B and C, service B requires services C and D, service C requires service D, and service D has no dependencies.
How can I specify this dependency chain such that each service has its own compose file with it's list of primary dependencies only (i.e. service A does not have to know to list service D because service C requires it), and a simple docker compose up will start all required services.
Using the include keyword does not work
In the example of trying to run service A with the following compose files:
a/compose.yml
version: "3.8"
include:
 - ../b/compose.yaml
 - ../c/compose.yaml
services:
  a: ...

b/compose.yml
version: "3.8"
include:
 - ../c/compose.yaml
 - ../d/compose.yaml
services:
  b: ...

c/compose.yml
version: "3.8"
include:
 - ../d/compose.yaml
services:
  c: ...

d/compose.yml
version: "3.8"
services:
  d: ...

This results in an error message: "services.d conflicts with imported resource".
Using the -f command does not work
If I remove the include statements from the above compose files, I can then run
docker compose up -f "../b/compose.yaml" -f "../c/compose.yaml"

Doing this, I don't get an error of conflicting resources, but now service D is not started, and so calls to services B and C fail.
It seems like this would be a fairly typical use case for running a microservices architecture locally, but I can't find the solution here.

To resolve this problem, as well as to provide configuration options for multiple environments, the "extends" key can be utilized in scenarios like this.
services:
  a: ...
  b:
    extends:
      file: ../b/compose.yaml
      service: b
    # Can add more to b in this compose here
  c:
    extends:
      files: ../c/compose.yaml
      service: c
  d:
    extends:
      files: ../d/compose.yaml
      service: d

